# Stop Server attacks

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I had many attacks on the port 1433 of my DB . I renamed the SA account and changed the DB port (my problem was solved thanks to  [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)  ) . But i went to the windows server logs again i found some attacks (unsuccessful login ) .

My questions are :

on which port the user was trying to access the machine (3389 ?)  .

Can i get more info on what the user was trying to do ?

How to stop these attacks ?

Any comment would help

[image]

Comment: database should not be available on internet, or only from some IP, why your MSSQL is visible from internet ? 3389 is your Terminal server port. thoose request are common Bruteforce attack...Logs are saying bad username or password is that not enought ? :P

Comment: My DB is on a port (very secret)  as i need to access it from outside to use some reporting that query the database directly . I will remadiate this later . So the user was trying to do 3389 access ?

Comment: more infos in details tab, i presume it is 3389 as it is default brute force attack on windows

Comment: btw when attacks occur, i temp block the ip for the day, get ip provider, and report ip to the abuse mail of the company

Comment: How can i find the IP of this chineese pirate ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a very secret port. Automated scanners access them all in seconds.  If your outside reporting queries come form a fixed (set of) ip(s), then you should just allow that in the firewall.

Comment: Yes you are right automated scanners can loop over all ports in fews seconds . I will now set up some fixed ip  (very few ) so that i can be safe all the time . But can scanner make its ip as my ip  (emulate) and then tries to access the system ?

Comment: They can't know wich IP is allowed

Comment: them IP are in Details tab; you can report them to their provider, they will do action to fix this

Comment: the IP is empty .  <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data>

Comment: Even if you figure out who's doing it, you're not going to be able to prosecute.  A firewall admins pastime is sitting back and watching the millions of port scans hit their public interface on a daily basis.  Per Froggiz, there is no solution beyond removing the server from public exposure and building a proper infrastructure to protect and drop malicious traffic.

Answer (score 2):

These will be automated scans ...

- Configure your firewall with a  default DROP policy on incoming connections.
- Only allow incoming connections on ports that are in use.
- Restrict access to ports that are not public to specified IP addresses.
- Don't have your database exposed to the wider internet.

Comment: I do not understand the first point .    I am allowing only ports in use , i cant restrict address to specific ip as i am mobile . I need to access the DB from anywhere in the world . I am thinking about VPN  that would help i imagine  to acheive the last 3 points ?

Comment: If you can guarantee that the VPN server will always have 1 public IP on the other end of your tunnel. Otherwise, do you have a firewall at all or does your ISP provide you with a managed firewall service?

Comment: @JavaMain 3389 is RDP port, are you allowing RDP too?  Yes the best thing to do would be firewall off the server and setup a VPN. 3389 isn't encrypted so it isn't secure. I assumed you have enable encryption on your SQL server too?

Comment: Actually i am on amazon webservice using the EC2 machines whatever is there i am using it . Yes the IP should be fixed ip .

Comment: I am on SQL standard  so no TDE available . encrypting and decrypting is expensive in performace i guess .